# How to do pm2 log formatting?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2, pm2-logrotate

Hi I have implemented pm2.Now I am getting timestamp in each line.

//Current log

```
2021-05-04T00:34:49:       { MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
2021-05-04T00:34:49:           at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Article\snode_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:29:11)
2021-05-04T00:34:49:           at basicWriteValidations (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:448:51)
2021-05-04T00:34:49:           at Server.insert (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:536:16)
2021-05-04T00:34:49:           at Server.insert (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:385:17)
2021-05-04T00:34:49:           at executeCommands (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\ordered.js:455:23)
2021-05-04T00:34:49:           at resultHandler (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\ordered.js:425:5)
2021-05-04T00:34:49:           at C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:461:18
2021-05-04T00:34:49:           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

I want to achieve this log format means one time timestamp for each error and log level in pm2

```
2021-05-04T00:34:49: [Error]       { MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
          at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Article\snode_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:29:11)
          at basicWriteValidations (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:448:51)
          at Server.insert (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:536:16)
          at Server.insert (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:385:17)
          at executeCommands (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\ordered.js:455:23)
          at resultHandler (C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\ordered.js:425:5)
          at C:\Articles\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:461:18
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Here is my config file:-

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "app",
    script : "./app.js",
    error_file : "/err.log",
    out_file : "/out.log",
    time: true

  }]
}
```

Thanks in advance!!